# Beginning in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to learn IA32 Assembly and don't know how to start. I am trying to make a simple program that takes two inputs (a1 and a2), adds them together, and then returns the sum. Another program that would also modify a given inputted virtual memory location and scale (multiply) its value by 5 and replace the number with this new multiple. A third program would write the String "helloworld" as individual chars in a sequence in virtual memory. The problem is, I don't even know where to start. The book I am reading is very confusing and has little to no examples on any given covered topic.

Ok, here are my futile attempts. I don't even know how to begin the third one.

---

First Program:

```
movl (memloc), %eax    // load the first argument
movl (memloc), %ecx    // load the second argument
addl %ecx, %eax        // add them
ret                    // return
```

Notes: By 'memloc' I mean the memory location. The book says these practice programs are supposed to have parameters but I don't know how to go about this in assembly.

---

Second Program:

```
movl (memloc), %eax    // load the number
movl (memloc), %ecx    // load it again
addl %ecx, %eax        // do this four times to get 5 times the original number
addl %ecx, %eax
addl %ecx, %eax
addl %ecx, %eax
ret                    // return
```

Notes: The same notes from the First Program about the 'memloc' statement. I have no idea on this one.

---

Third Program:

I have absolutely no idea how to do the third program. I know that it would require some 'movl' statements from the registers to the memory. But that is all.

Comment: Try googling to learn the basics and then post your attempted code (even if it doesn't work) and then we can help debug it and point you in the right direction. Here's one great resource: http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs107/IA32_Cheat_Sheet.pdf

Comment: When I first started IA32 assembly, many years ago, my favourite reference was the Art Of Assembly: http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/www.artofasm.com/index.html

Comment: I attempted to code the programs. For the third I gave a basic description of what I would need to be the main mechanism accomplishing the task.

Comment: If you are using 'call' to access your functions, then the arguments you pass to that function will be pushed on to the stack: `push 10; push 20; call MySumFunc` and can be accessed via stack pointer: ESP

Comment: I'm not sure if I am using 'call.' The text says that the first function should have a prototype: int astr(int i1, int i2);